# Cross-checking Driver's License Against DMV Using MySQL DB or PHP Script?

Tags: php, ios

Ok, so I am coming into this a little blind on how to go about allowing this app to store and check one's driver's license ID against the DMV or some other government agency. Basically, everything will be stored locally on the App, but then there needs to be a verification process either through using a PHP script to connect to DMV to check against if the ID is real and valid/not expired, or either we need to set up our own DB and still check against a government record of some sort. How could we go about this and which method is more recommended?

Just need some basic direction is all... Not having any luck finding a script that sends information securely to a DMV API that checks if a Driver's License # is valid or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software development, not security.

Comment: Well, it is about security because I was wanting to know which direction I should go (in words not code) on how to check, securely, against a Driver's License Number or how that would happen. Sorry if it is still off-topic, feel free to delete this post if it is... Just wanting to understand best, secure way to check a license ID through PHP. Just wasn't sure if someone would know the best way to securely go about this using PHP, really. Maybe API isn't best way or the right question.

Comment: this assumes that the information is even accessible and if it is accessible, then the answer will be to follow whatever the policies are of the organization providing access to the data.  (Most likely a SSL protected web service call.)  This is a run of the mill programing question with some government aspects, but nothing security relevant as the implementation of the security will have already been determined for you by the provider.  The actual implementation of the client is a programing concern.  Hope that helps clarify the scope of the site and good luck.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate any direction I can get. Tells me where I need to start at least :)

Comment: To start, contact the DMV you're interested in integrating with, and find out if they even offer programmatic access to the data.  If they do, find out how they offer it.  It's only going to be if they offer it in multiple formats that you'll have to make a decision at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Companies like Intellicheck sell packages that validate driver's licenses. You might want to start there.

Comment: that's a great suggestion, thanks! Sorry that I misunderstood the purpose of this website. I think what I have so far is sufficient regarding my situation.